# Typescript interface with function called "new"

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I'm trying to write a TS definition for an external library that has a factory function that is called "new". The problem is that adding a function called "new" in the interface refers to the constructors type.

Is there any way to escape the new keyword or get this type working?

```
export interface Container {

  //This is what I want, except as a regular function, not the constructor
  new<T>(TConstructor: new () => T, locals?: object): T;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a pair of quotes will suffice:

```
export interface Container {

  //This is what I want, except as a regular function, not the constructor
  'new'<T>(TConstructor: new () => T, locals?: object): T;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just quote the method identifier:

```
export interface Container {

  'new'<T>(TConstructor: new () => T, locals?: object): T;

}

declare let o: Container;
o.new(null!)
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQhU2TTgG8AoSuOAejoBUALBAZ0Q4HdnN4BJOF0woANHFC4w8TB0xwowAOYBXADaYocdCqTYYCIuKQR4MZnmxE2MKCv3QacAORJgXZwB5GAPgAUjIRINnYOUABccG5ccH4AlHAAvD5wjOJqENiYamwA-JEQAEYAVsD6cZGMANzUAL7UACZlGopwasDwEJFBMCRuUDUQAHTRfkjqagCEcUA)